# login and register with password_hash PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-hash

What? how do I check the password from DB? I also noticed that I registered 2 accounts with the same password but their hash value is not the same. The problem is that the password_verify returns false.**The password dont match with the hashed string**

I just followed the PHP manual password_hash and password_verify. I already searched not just in StackOverflow but I just can't get the answer.

LOGIN

```
     public function login_user($username, $password){
        $this->db->where(['username' => $username]);
        $result = $this->db->get('user');

        //if($result->num_rows() >= 1){
        if($result->num_rows() >= 1)
        {
            // $user = $result->result_array();same

            $user = $result->row_array(0); 
            $pw = $user['password'];
            // $pass = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            // var_dump(password_verify($pass, $pw));
            // var_dump($pass);
            // var_dump($pw);

            // die();
             if(password_verify($password, $pw)){
                return $user;
             }

        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

REGISTER

```
    public function add_user($username, $password, $type){
        $data = [
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT),
            'type' => $type
        ];
        $this->db->insert('user', $data);
    }
```

Comment: "same password but their hash value is not the same" yes this is correct behavior.

Comment: yeah i think i read it also on the manual that the salt changes, so how can I check when the user login?

Comment: _"how do I check the password from DB?"_ - Just like you are doing. Fetch the hash for the username and verify it with against the supplied password with [password_verify()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). What's your actual issue here? Isn't this your code?

Comment: your question is unclear, please provide us with your problem.

Comment: yeah it is my code but the password_verify return false. 
if(password_verify($password, $pw)){
                return $user;
             }
this code return false so the user cant login

Comment: If your function is returning `false` then it's your DB query not returning rows (or your `if` somehow being wrong). If the password were not verifying correctly, then you'd be getting `null`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol as you can see I have comments there, the var_dump my query returned a row. I already checked it.

Comment: In your DB, what's the length of the `password` column? It needs to be _at least_ 60 chars (preferably longer to be future proof).

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the password strings from the front end in the same exact way each time (e.g. no special functions like `strtollower` or adding extra characters)?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($password, $pw);` before you're trying to verify it and check that both those variables contain what you expect.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ohhh you already solved it thanks the varchar before is 50 i changed it now to 255. whew i thought i'm not following the php manual correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to validate user.

Where your `$this->db->where(['username' => $username]);` You dont need `[]`

To get single item I would use like `$query->row('password');` up to you.

Here example how I would validate_password.

```
public function validate_password($username, $password){

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows() == 1){

        $input_password = $password;
        $stored_password = $query->row('password');

        if (password_verify($input_password, $stored_password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } 

    return false;
}
```

On your controller in success part of form or you can use as callback function

```
if ($this->some_model->validate_password($this->input->post('username'), $this->input->post('password')) {

    // Once is success full have another function that can get user information via username.

    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing what you've changed and why it would work differently than the original code? The OP does say in the comments that they do get a result from the DB.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried my best to explain it you can improve it if you wan't I am not good at explaining things.

Comment: That's fine. It's just that only have "try this" isn't that constructive :-)

Comment: i already did the condition i just removed it to check what the password_verify returns.

i have this 
if (password_verify($password, $user['password'])) {
                    return $user;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

Comment: Make sure you are getting the post correct `var_dump($this->input->post())`

Comment: its already solved, thanks to @MagnusEriksson

Comment: @KarlJucutan - Write an answer explaining how you solved it. Then you can accept that answer so we all know that this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The password_verify($password, $pw) returns false because the hash password is not atleast 60 char. the column password from my database before is only 50 char, now I changed it to 255 char. Then problem solved!. thanks to Magnus Eriksson :)